# Google Sheets Script return current value before grabbing external data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet which grabs data from an external source based on the value in the corresponding row. This sheet is then published to web as CSV.
The issue is that randomly the values come out in the CSV as "#NAME?" or "loading..."

Is there a way I can stop these fields from updating when accessing via CSV.

Or is there a way I can write a function like

```
function getValue(id)

 start thread or similar background process
   load external resource parse
   update the cell value

 return cell current value
```

Where the function will start a background thread, but instantly return the current value so it never appears to change. Then inside the thread it will update the data if it gets a response. This would fix the 'loading...' issue, but I don't think it would fix the "#NAME?" issue.

Comment: May I clarify, please correct me if I'm wrong. This question does not concern the **creation** of the csv file, but rather the **use** of the csv at a later date when it is imported into a Google spreadsheet. Would you please provide a sample of the csv file.

Comment: This is 
External API -> Google Sheets using Google Sheet Script -> Publish to Web as CSV
The Google Sheet has the value, but the Publish to Web as CSV (randomly) has "#NAME?" or "loading..." in the results.
Sometimes hitting the CSV URL multiple times will result in returning the correct values.
On my script that consumes the Google Sheet CSV I can detect if any of the fields have #NAME? and append something like &timestamp=X to the end and keep looping through. Sometimes it takes 3 attempts, sometimes it stops at 5 which is where I have an artificial limit to prevent never ending loading

Answer (score 1):

I guess the cell values come from a formula or from an external source, so in this case the [getDisplayValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) is more apropiate, as it gets the value of the cell just as you see it in your screen.

This script gets the values this way and re-writes them in the same spot, but as plain text (or integer, depending of the values you have). So if you export the data as CSV **after** running this, your issue should be solved.

Also, any formula or function in the cells **will be removed**, so make sure this is what you need before running it.

```
function main() {

  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sprsheet.getActiveSheet();

  var values = sheet.getRange("A1:A10").getDisplayValues(); //Put the column and rows you use

  for (var i = 1; i < values.length + 1; i++){ //i is the row you start at
    sheet.getRange("A"+i).setValue(values[i - 1]); //We deduce 1 as the array starts at 0

  }

}
```

Keep in mind that this is for just one column, if you are using more, then it would be a 2D array and the code would be different, adding another nested `for` loop.